# Angular2 How to override baseURL inside package.json

Tags: angular, package, environment

Hi I am using environment to set global baseurl but I also want to know how to override baseurl within package.json.

What I mean is,

this is my environment.dev.ts file

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiUrl: 'https://test.com'
}
```

And in package.json, I'm using this script to build my app

```
"build": "ng build --env=dev",
```

But I also want to know how to override this baseurl by changing something in the package.json (like type in 'baseurl' itself)

for example..

```
"build": "ng build --env=dev.baseURL='otherurl.com'"
```

Please help!

Thanks!